# Expression Blend on VS 2010

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, expression-blend

After deep searching and much reading, I could not find my way to work on Expression Blend with WPF in Visual Studio 2010. I had already installed Expression Blend 3.0 and 4.0 from the following links and restarted VS 2010 and I still cannot open Blend or see the "Open in Expression Blend" option when I right click the XAML file in VS explorer.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=10801

https://www.microsoft.com/en-my/download/details.aspx?id=22829

I would appreciate it if someone out there can provide clear steps on how to install Blend to make it work on VS 2010.

Comment: VS 2010 is a bit dated at this point. Do you have to use that version? The reason I ask is the later versions of Visual Studio all include a newer version of Expression Blend as part of their install packages.

Comment: @JeffR. Unfortunately yes, I have to use this version as provided by my employer.

Comment: Have you tried running Blend from the Windows Start menu by itself? If that works, try loading your project from within Blend itself. I believe that version could be run side-by-side with VS.